# do i have to test my app in testFlight thorugh itunesConnect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded an app to iTunes Connect. as far as my understanding, i think there is no any option to submit it for review without to test it through testFlight.
Is there a way to pass this stage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to go through testflight before submitting. If it doesn't work then there is another issue (missing metadata for example)